# Clojure keyword example security issue

Tags: security, clojure

After reading this question [Security implications of Clojure keyword creation from user data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869371/security-implications-of-clojure-keyword-creation-from-user-data), and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883569/1327651), I am trying to find a case where I can demonstrate the issue in the REPL.
Here is an attempt:

```
user> *clojure-version*
{:major 1, :minor 8, :incremental 0, :qualifier nil}
user> (def a (atom 0))
#'user/a
user> (defn bad-fn []
        (println "called ")
        (swap! a inc))
#'user/bad-fn
user> @a
0
user> (keyword "#=(bad-fn)")
:#=(bad-fn)
user> @a
0
```

How can I reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not that calling `keyword` on a string will immediately execute any code embedded in the string, but that if you wanted to store the string representation of, say, `(keyword "foo #=(println :bar)")` in a file and then consume that file using `read`, you'd end up executing the embedded code.

Of course it's not advisable to `read` user-provided strings at all, but that question was about security, so the answers (Brian's and mine) describe security issues that may result from a misuse of various facilities in conjunction with the `keyword` function that the question named specifically.

Using `clojure.edn` (unavailable in 2010 when that question was posted) mitigates the `#=` issue, but not the broader issue that one should not expect to be able to read back the string representation of `(keyword <arbitrary-string>)` as the same keyword, whichever reader one uses. Failure to take that into account can easily result in data corruption.

Comment: Short example (data corruption): `{(keyword "a :b") :c}`

Comment: Keywords are supposed to be interned [symbols](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_symbols), in which spaces are not valid characters.

Comment: @Thumbnail Firstly, the original question from 2010 was about the actual security implications of calling `clojure.core/keyword` on user data. `clojure.core/keyword` does not validate its input to check whether it contains spaces, so while the spec may not admit keywords with spaces, if one passes to it arbitrary user-provided strings, one may absolutely end up creating such keywords. Secondly, the reader deliberately accepts (spaceless) keywords that are "incorrect" according to that spec – back in 2013, a patch was committed that made it more strict, but broke existing code and was reverted.

Comment: References for the final point: [CLJ-1252](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1252), [clojure-dev thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure-dev/HeFr_jeuTnE/JZtPpQkK2dEJ) ([key message by Alex Miller](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure-dev/HeFr_jeuTnE/-53WooNCIFAJ)), [the CLJ-1252 commit](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/39aa021e83b4d5bc2d7c3b13c56c04daee4c27d0), [the reverting commit](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/249479ecebcb0cfca9e6a1d528e3d7f0b3ca7dc6).

Comment: Also note that the symbol literal spec currently excludes `<`, `>` and `=` – see [this issue](https://github.com/clojure/clojure-site/pull/162). Not that this is directly related to how `keyword` behaves, but it goes to show that even the reader is way more permissive with symbol and keyword literals than the spec would suggest. </end tangent> ;-)